# PyQt4 window does not appears while running the program but appears on ipython

Tags: python, pyqt4

I was trying out PyQt4. and tried this code.

```
import sys                                                                    
from PyQt4 import QtGui                                                       

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)                                            
window = QtGui.QWidget()                                                      
window.show()  
print 'end'
```

This above code works when i try it on on `ipython`, But it doesn’t when i write them into a file and run it. I also tried changing the permission by `chmod +x`. The code actually runs(the reason i added a print statement at the end to confirm if the code is running till the end), i don’t get a window.

im running python 2.7.6 on ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to start the Qt event loop by calling `app.exec_()` once you have initialised the widgets and called `show()` on your main window.

Comment: it worked, why is it so only on linux and not on windows, and i haven't yet tried on mac.

Comment: It is to do with the way ipython works on those platforms I think. I'm pretty sure there is a duplicate of this question somewhere on SO but I can't find it. In short, I think ipython is launching the Qt event loop for another reason, and so it makes your program work too. If you run with the normal python console I don't think you will see the same behaviour