# PyQt GUI Window NOT showing on VirtualBox Linux Mint

Tags: qt, pyqt4, virtual-machine, virtualbox, linux-mint

I've installed PyQt4 on my Linux Cinnamon Mint on my VirtualBox Machine (using : sudo apt-get install python-qt4) and tried running this code :

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtGui.QWidget()


window.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 300)


window.setWindowTitle("PyQT Tuts!")


window.show()
```

It compiles without errors, but I do not see any Window for the show method.

I'm new in this so simple instructions will be appreciated.

Thanks for the read.

Comment: I suggest you work through this: [PyQt4 tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyQt4 window does not appears while running the program but appears on ipython](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046317/pyqt4-window-does-not-appears-while-running-the-program-but-appears-on-ipython)

Answer (score 1):

In Linux you have to include **sys.exit(app.exec_())** below your **window.show()**

Example:

```
    import sys
    from PyQt4 import QtGui

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = QtGui.QWidget()
    window.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 300)
    window.setWindowTitle("whatever")

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

That's the only problem i can see.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtGui.QWidget()
    window.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 300)
    window.setWindowTitle("PyQT Tuts!")
    window.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```