# PyQt5 Error With Mac Compatibility

Tags: python, windows, macos, pyqt5, compatibility

I recently wrote an application with a PyQt5 UI, and the program works perfectly on windows. However, running on a Mac, the UI pops up but is no longer interactive; none of the buttons or entry fields are functional and every element is greyed out. The code is the same and doesn't appear to contain anything specific to either operating system. The program was written and runs on Windows 10 and ran into trouble on Mac OSX El Capitan.

How can I resolve this issue?

Below is an example. The following code will provide a fully interactive UI on Windows, but a non-functioning "frozen" and greyed-out UI on Mac, even when built from scratch on Mac.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'test2.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.10.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(403, 365)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(19, 9, 361, 181))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.directory = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.directory.setObjectName("directory")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.directory, 5, 3, 1, 1)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_3, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.filename = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.filename.setObjectName("filename")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.filename, 4, 3, 1, 1)
        self.URL = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.URL.setObjectName("URL")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.URL, 3, 3, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_4, 2, 3, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.checkBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.checkBox_2.setObjectName("checkBox_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.checkBox_2)
        self.checkBox_3 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.checkBox_3.setObjectName("checkBox_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.checkBox_3)
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.checkBox)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3, 6, 3, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 190, 361, 153))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_3.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget_3")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget_3)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.main_out = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.verticalLayoutWidget_3)
        self.main_out.setObjectName("main_out")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.main_out)
        self.progress = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.verticalLayoutWidget_3)
        self.progress.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progress.setObjectName("progress")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.progress)
        self.cancel_button = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(self.verticalLayoutWidget_3)
        self.cancel_button.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.cancel_button.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.cancel_button.setObjectName("cancel_button")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.cancel_button)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.cancel_button.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept)
        self.cancel_button.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "URL:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Save As:"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Save In:"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "TextLabel"))
        self.checkBox_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "CheckBox"))
        self.checkBox_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "CheckBox"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("Dialog", "CheckBox"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyQt4 window does not appears while running the program but appears on ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046317/pyqt4-window-does-not-appears-while-running-the-program-but-appears-on-ipython)